# How to get stdout from subprocess.Popen elegantly with timeout check?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

PC System: Ubuntu 18.04
Python version: 3.6.9
When execute command like "adb logcat" by subprocess.Popen, I want to get the stdout and decide whether to stop the subprocess based on the keyword in it.
If the keyword does not appear for a long time, i will stop it too.  The first attempt is as follows

```
import time
import subprocess

cmd = "adb logcat"
timeout = 10
adb_shell_pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
start_time = time.time()
for info in iter(adb_shell_pipe.stdout.readline, ""):
    if "keyword" in info:
        print("Find keyword!")
        # Omit kill process
        break
    if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
        print("Fail!")
        # Omit kill process
        break
```

The code succeeded in doing what I need, but I found that if there is no next output from the tenth seconds after the subprocess starts, the program will not end with "Fail!" until the next output.
I think it's because `readline()` blocks to read the output. So, i set the stdout to non-block by `fcntl` like the following code

```
import os
import time
import fcntl
import subprocess

# Command was replaced to create test scenarios
cmd = "adb shell"
timeout = 10
adb_shell_pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

fd = adb_shell_pipe.stdout.fileno()
fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

count = 0
start_time = time.time()
while adb_shell_pipe.poll() is None:
    count += 1
    info = adb_shell_pipe.stdout.readline()
    if info and "keyword" in info:
        print("Find keyword!")
        # Omit kill process
        break
    if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
        print("Fail!")
        # Omit kill process
        break
print(count)
```

```
# Output
Fail!
4131304
```

As shown above, the results were as expected. However, it execute `readline()` 4131304 times in 10 seconds, It may waste resources, and the `fcntl` module cannot be used on Windows.
So, is there a more elegant, generic way to implement this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe in every iteration call an async function which will kill the process after 10 secs, and also in every iteration kill the previous async call, like

```
killer_coroutine = None
while loop:
   # stuff...
   if killer_coroutine:
      killer_coroutine.cancel()
   killer_coroutine = async_func()
```

so if the loop stops at some point, the process will get killed.
I am not sure if this would work, maybe worth a shot.