# Make readline() blocking until a new non-empty value arrives

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, polling

I'm reading data from USB serial with:

```
s = serial.Serial(port="COM1", baudrate=115200, write_timeout=0.010, timeout=0.010)
while polling:
    r = s.readline().decode("ascii")
    if r != '':
        v = float(r)
        print('new value', v)
    time.sleep(0.005)
```

I'm expecting data at a rate of 50 values per second, but in order to not miss anything, I'm only waiting 5 ms (200 Hz). This works but it is not optimal.

Is there a way to make `readline()` blocking? i.e. it should't `return` anything until new data comes. This way I could totally avoid the `time.sleep(...)` with the arbitrary `0.005` duration.

Problem: it seems that the hardware returns an empty string (or an empty string with newline) each time I do `readline()` when there is no new data.

Comment: I think `readline()`is  already block. I had a similar problem when I used `readline` on Linux to read data from pipe. I changed readline from blocking to non-blocking by `fcntl`.  It may help for you [How to get stdout from subprocess.Popen elegantly with timeout check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644398/how-to-get-stdout-from-subprocess-popen-elegantly-with-timeout-check)

Comment: @CN-LanBao Thank you. Do you think the problem might come from the fact the hardware always answer an empty string (or an empty string + newline) even if there is no new data?

Comment: Yeah, that's very possible, maybe you can use param like `.read(size=1)` to set the bytes read at a time?  @Basj

Comment: Isn't it good to judge whether [in_waiting](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting) is 1 or more and [readline()](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.readline) only then?