# Python Run `subprocess.Popen` With Timeout and Get `stdout` at Runtime

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to create a function to run a `command` with `timeout`, but at the same time, get standard output (`stdout`) to display. I saw some answers, but not exactly what I am looking for.

- [How to run a process with timeout and still get stdout at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801202/how-to-run-a-process-with-timeout-and-still-get-stdout-at-runtime) (this is similar, but I need to return a `Popen` object.
- [How to get stdout from subprocess.Popen elegantly with timeout check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644398/how-to-get-stdout-from-subprocess-popen-elegantly-with-timeout-check) (also similar)

Function signature goes:

```py
def run_with_timeout(command, timeout)
```

So far I am able to get `stdout` to print at runtime, but I am not sure what's an robust way to timeout the application. Is there a robust way to do the timeout, or is there a better approach to this? I tried `process.wait(timeout=timeout)` and `process.communicate(timeout=timeout)`, but doesn't seem to work. I am trying to avoid using threads as well...

```py
def run_with_timeout(command, timeout):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True,
        text=True,
    )

    output = ''

    try:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            output += line
            print(line)

        process.stdout.close()
        process.out = output

    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as te:
        process.kill()

    return process
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to avoid using threads here? This is a very solid use case for a simple thread that does nothing but delay and send a SIGTERM; I'm hard-pressed to think of a case against that approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, mainly because we currently are using threads, but there seem to be a stability issue, so I guess the question would be, how to properly implement the thread in a robust way?

Comment: I think you're real underlying question here may be the issue you're having with the threading module

Comment: @Matt, i am running this function along with `pytest` in a Jenkins pipeline for an application, say `ping` or `nslookup` to see if they can run for some `timeout` time, but sometimes I get intermediate crashes, but I never seen it happen before using threads, so I am wondering if I am just implementing threading incorrectly and what's the proper way to do it

Comment: Hard to say just from that, I'd open a separate question for it

Comment: Really depends on the details. Most of the times I've seen threading cause interpreter crashes involve C modules calling libraries that aren't thread-safe or other corner cases that wouldn't apply here.

Comment: Another option is using `select.select((process.stdout.fileno(),), (), ()), remaining_timeout)` before `process.stdout.readline()`. This works on Unix-like systems (not Microsoft Windows) only.

Comment: make sense, unfortunately i need to get it working on all the platforms

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it on Unix-like systems (e.g. Linux and macOS, but not Microsoft Windows) without threads. You can use `preexec_fn=` with `signal.alarm`.

```py
import signal
import subprocess

def run_with_timeout(command, timeout):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True,
        text=True,
        preexec_fn=lambda: signal.alarm(timeout),
    )

    output = ''

    try:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            output += line
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))

        process.stdout.close()
        process.out = output

    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as te:
        process.kill()

    return process

print(run_with_timeout(('/bin/sh', '-c', 'while sleep .6; do N=$((N+1)); echo $N; done'), 3))
```

It works this way:

- `preexec_fn=` executes `signal.alarm(timeout)` in the child process just before running the `command`.
- `signal.alarm(timeout)` asks the kernel to deliver a SIGARLM signal to the (child) process after the specified number of seconds.
- Thi SIGALRM signal kills the child process by default.
- When the child process is killed, the write end of the `process.stdout` pipe is closed, which causes an EOF in the read end, which causes `iter(...)` to return None, which causes the `for line in ...` loop to end.

Limitations:

- It doesn't work on Microsoft Windows, because there is no `signal.alarm` (neither the kernel mechanism nor the Python function).
- If the child process creates child processes of its own, those processes won't receive the SIGALRM signal, and they may keep running indefinitely, not closing the write end of the `process.stdout` pipe.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up trying to optimize the function using threading, not sure if this is the best approach, but work with both timeout and output to console.

If there's a better approach or method of doing this, please let me know :)

```py
def run_with_timeout(command, timeout):
    # Create the process
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True,
        text=True,
        )

    # The thread function to capture the output
    def display_output():
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            print(line.strip())
        process.stdout.close()

    # Create the thread
    t = threading.Thread(target=display_output)

    # Start the thread
    t.start()

    try:
        # Wait for the process to finish or `timeout` is reached
        process.wait(timeout=timeout)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        # End the process with `SIGTERM` signal
        process.kill()

    # Wait for the thread to finish
    t.join(timeout=timeout)

    return process
```